# Data is getting sorted while joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join 2 tables for example:

Table1

```
Col1
---
3
4
2
1
```

Table2

```
Col1    Col2
----    ----
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

When I join:

```
select T2.Col2 from Table2 T2,Table1.T1 where T1.Col1=T2.Col1;
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

But I want:

```
C
D
B
A
```

Comment: Without an `order by` the database is free to return the rows in any order. What logic does your desired output have? Seems rather un-sorted as well.

Answer (score 2):

You always need an `ORDER BY` if you want the results of your query to be sorted.

The base notion of relational databases and sql is a set, and a set comes without order. Any putative orderings that you experience when querying without the `order by` clause are arbitrary - which means in particular that they will not be stable across multiple invocations of the same query.

It is  unclear from your example what the sorting criteria would be, lets just assume that there was a column `Table2.Col3` that contained the rank in a global ordering of your data. Then your desired result could be obtained by:

```
  select T2.Col2 
    from Table2 T2
    JOIN Table1 T1 ON ( T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 )
ORDER BY T2.Col3
       ;
```

[This Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11acf/1) demonstrates the full-fledged example.

NB:
I have adapted your example query to the standard join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

to do this `order by` the only one way is add an additional column that will specify `order by` for data in table1. database cannot guarantee the order of data it physical table and you need `order by` to return them in specific order

```
select T2.Col2 
  from Table2 T2,Table1 T1 
    where T1.Col1=T2.Col1
    order by t1.order_column  

    COL2
1   C
2   D
3   B
4   A

create table table1 (col1 int, order_column int);
create table table2 (col1 int, col2 varchar2(10));

insert into table1 values(3,1);
insert into table1 values(4,2);
insert into table1 values(2,3);
insert into table1 values(1,4);

insert into table2 values(1,'A');
insert into table2 values(2,'B');
insert into table2 values(3,'C');
insert into table2 values(4,'D');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve this unless you have another column in Table1 that determines the sort. Usually, it's another primary key / big integer column that holds the order in which values are inserted.